# Multiply two lists with dicts python

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = [{'the': '0.181'}, {'to': '0.115'}, {'a': '0.093'}, {'of': '0.084'}, {'and': '0.078'}]

list2 = [{'the': '1.010'}, {'to': '1.010'}, {'a': '1.000'}, {'of': '1.102'}, {'and': '1.228'}]
```

As result I am trying to get a new list like this:

```
[{'the': 'list1 *list2'}, {'to': 'list1*list2'}, 
 {'a': 'list1*list2'}, {'of': 'list1*list2'}, {'and': 'list1*list2'}]
```

So my question is, how can I multiply these two lists?

Comment: How should the output be?

Comment: @Cardstdani One list with all five words and the number in the two lists multiplied for each word.

Comment: Look into using numpy or pandas for this. One comment: There isn't a single tuple in your example code, I just see lists, dicts, strings.

Comment: Ohh okay thanks! I am new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the list are already sorted in the same order I'd suggest to `zip` them and apply the multiplication you want

```
list1 = [{'the': '0.181'}, {'to': '0.115'}, {'a': '0.093'}, {'of': '0.084'}, {'and': '0.078'}]
list2 = [{'the': '1.010'}, {'to': '1.010'}, {'a': '1.000'}, {'of': '1.102'}, {'and': '1.228'}]

result = []
for pair1, pair2 in zip(list1, list2):
    k1, v1 = list(pair1.items())[0]
    k2, v2 = list(pair2.items())[0]
    if k1 != k2:
        raise Exception(f"Malformed data ({k1},{v1}).({k2},{v2})")
    result.append({k1: float(v1) * float(v2)})

print(result)
# [{'the': 0.18281}, {'to': 0.11615}, {'a': 0.093}, {'of': 0.09256800000000001}, {'and': 0.095784}]
```